# Salesforce Sandbox Problem

Tags: administration, sandbox, user-admin

I am unable to Login into Sandbox account,Actually we have 3 Production Environment for this  production account i have only one sandbox Account,in that 3 production accounts i changed one of my production password by using that new password i can't able to login into sandbox account may i know what i have to do.. How can i solve this issuse.the 3 production environment having different logins, and different passwords.

My deploy Image  [image]

Comment: Which instance was the sandbox created under? Have you ever logged into a sandbox before?

Comment: @curtisk cs15, we are using enterprise edition

Comment: @curtisk above i add a image once check it, give me suggestions how to login into that.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to ask any other developer / system administrator that has access to this sandbox to reset your password there.

If you've never logged in to this sandbox before there's high chance your email address there is broken (firstname.lastname@example.com **.test**) so clicking "Forgot my password" on the  https://test.salesforce.com won't work.

Alternatively (if no one can access it) - it's a pretty old one, copied in June. It's tempting to just delete or refresh it? Is there any development done there that you're afraid you'll lose?

Comment: above message i paste the deploy image that means there is no deployments in our org. so shall i refresh my sandbox...??

Comment: No, I'm talking about classes, pages, fields etc that somebody might have created in that sandbox but they're "work in progress", they were never pushed to production. If you'll refresh this sandbox you'll lose all such data. But there's no way of knowing it from outside, you (or somebody else) would have to log in there to examine the differences between it & production, Setup Audit Trail etc. Do you have a spare sandbox license? You can simply create new one with different name if you're not sure what to do with that one.

Comment: actually we don't have any spare licence we have only 1 developer sandbox licence.

Comment: Just ask around your team of admins/developers. If nobody logged to that one in long time and nobody remembers their passwords from June'13 I'd just refresh it.

Comment: just now i download the setupaudittrail data. in that i have to check any classes and vf pages are exist in sandbox. by using sandbox user name..??

Comment: But where did you download it from, production? This won't help much, the point is you don't know what was changed in that sandbox.

Comment: Thanq for suggestions.